# Why do LINQ to Entities does not recognize certain Methods?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-entities

Why cant I do this:

```
usuariosEntities usersDB = new usuariosEntities();      
foreach (DataGridViewRow user in dgvUsuarios.Rows)
{
   var rowtoupdate = 
       usersDB.usuarios.Where(
       u => u.codigo_usuario == Convert.ToInt32(user.Cells[0].Value)
       ).First();
   rowtoupdate.password = user.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
usersDB.SaveChanges();
```

And have to do this:

```
usuariosEntities usersDB = new usuariosEntities();      
foreach (DataGridViewRow user in dgvUsuarios.Rows)
{
   int usercode = Convert.ToInt32(user.Cells[0].Value);
   var rowtoupdate = 
       usersDB.usuarios.Where(u => u.codigo_usuario == usercode).First();
   rowtoupdate.password = user.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
usersDB.SaveChanges();
```

I must admit it is a more readable code but why cant this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing about it is that LINQ queries are transformed by the compiler into an expression tree. This expression tree is then converted into T-SQL and passed to the server. LINQ to SQL maps certain methods like String.Contains to the T-SQL equivalents.

In the first example, LINQ apparently does not map Convert.ToInt32 to anything and the exception is thrown. The reason it works in your second example is because the Convert.ToInt32 call is done *outside* of the query so it isn't part of the expression tree and doesn't need to be converted to T-SQL.

<strike>[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386970.aspx) describes how LINQ to SQL translates various data types, operators, and methods into T-SQL. (Although the documentation does suggest Convert.ToInt32 is supported so I'm not sure what else might be going on here.)</strike>

Sorry just realized this is ADO.NET Entity Framework, not LINQ to SQL. [This page lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) the ADO.NET Entity Framework mappings. It is a bit more restrictive, mostly because it needs to work with multiple providers.

Comment: Is there a way to make L2E map theese methods/functions to T-SQL functions?
+1 clear explanation

Comment: No, but if you create a user-defined function in SQL and add that to your data context, you can use them in your queries.

Comment: so if I am using mysql and add some stored procedure to my DB I can call it somehow?

Comment: I apologize I just realized I linked to LINQ to SQL documentation, not ADO.NET Entity Framework which has some more restrictions due to the fact that it needs to support several different providers. I am honestly not sure how EF supports MySQL stored procedures or functions.

Comment: but basically your answer is why... isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Because your LINQ to Ent. doesn't compile the query into MSIL with all the meta data, but simply translates the query into a few extantion methods and is bounded to lambda parsing abuilities of the languge. That means that

this code:
`var results =  from c in SomeCollection
               where c.SomeProperty < someValue * 2
               select new {c.SomeProperty, c.OtherProperty};`

is the same as this:

`var results =
     SomeCollection`
          `.Where(c => c.SomeProperty < someValue * 2)`
          `.Select(c => new {c.SomeProperty, c.OtherProperty});`